# How to change selected element class names

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to change selected buttons name and their classes, names are changing perfectly,, but i am little bit confusing to  change button classes, in the below code if i change class name all buttons classes are changing ,, how can i change only selected button class? please edit my below code and suggest me how to solve this..
[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/JPD84uYnoPWbOWqwCEUs?p=preview)

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.class = 'col-sm-12';
  $scope.textVal = 'click a button';
  $scope.selectedEvent = {};
  $scope.setText = function(element) {
    $scope.selectedEvent = element;
     $scope.textVal = element.currentTarget.innerHTML;
  };
  $scope.changeButtonText = function(){
    $scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
  };
    $scope.changetoLarge = function(){
    $scope.class = 'col-sm-12'
  }
  $scope.changetoMedium = function(){
    $scope.class = 'col-sm-6'
  }
  $scope.changetoSmall = function(){
    $scope.class = 'col-sm-4'
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myapp'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div>
  <button type="button" ng-class="class" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setText($event)">one</button>
  <button type="button" ng-class="class" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setText($event)">two</button>
  <button type="button" ng-class="class" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setText($event)">three</button>
</div><br>
<div>
<input type="text" ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeButtonText()">//change button name here//<br>

<input ng-click="changetoLarge()" type="radio" name="button">Large
<input ng-click="changetoMedium()" type="radio" name="button">medium
<input ng-click="changetoSmall()" type="radio" name="button">Small 
</div>//change button class here//
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Below is the script code... update this from previous answer.

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.class = '';
 $scope.textVal = 'click a button';

  $scope.selectedEvent = {};

  $scope.setText = function(element) {
    $scope.selectedEvent = element;
    $scope.textVal = element.currentTarget.innerHTML;
    var currentbtnClass = element.currentTarget.classList;
    alert(currentbtnClass[2])

    $scope.CSSClass = currentbtnClass[2]
    alert($scope.CSSClass)
  };
  $scope.changeButtonText = function(){
    $scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
  };

  $scope.setCSSClass=function(value){   
    angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).removeClass($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget.className)

    angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).addClass('btn btn-primary '+value)
  }
});



 Below is the HTML which you need to update..

  <button type="button" id="btn1" ng-model="btn1"  class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setText($event)">one</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn2" ng-model="btn2"  class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setText($event)">two</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn3" ng-model="btn3" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setText($event)">three</button>
</div><br>
<div>

<input type="text" ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeButtonText()">//change button name here//<br><br><br>

<input type="radio" ng-model="value1" name="rdbtn[]" value="col-sm-12" ng-click='setCSSClass(value1)' ng-checked="CSSClass==value1" >
<input type="radio" ng-model="value2" name="rdbtn[]" value="col-sm-6" ng-click='setCSSClass(value2)' ng-checked="CSSClass==value2">
<input type="radio" ng-model="value3" name="rdbtn[]" value="col-sm-3" ng-click='setCSSClass(value3)' ng-checked="CSSClass==value3"> 

</div>//change button class here//

Let me know if this helps you ?
```

Comment: hi,, u done a great job.. but i have a small doubt, what that is? To change Button value u have used **innerHTML** , If the value will be `<div><label>one</label></div>` like this what to use instead of _innerHTML_ ??

Comment: not working. In inputbox it was taking **<label>one</label>**

Comment: Yes. This is correct.. You are setting the HTML string to button.. then it will.. Let me know if you need any thing else..

Comment: In the above code replace this `<div ng-click="setText($event)"><label>User Name</label><input type="text" /></div>` in _one_ named button place. i want to show **User Name** in inputbox to edit, it was showing whole HTML tag between the DIV Tag .. can u pls check it out and do this to me?

Comment: Put below line in setText function of your controller..$scope.textVal = angular.element(element.currentTarget).children('label').html(); and dont forget to set ng-model in text box.

Comment: Hi Nimesh.. there is a small Issue.. :(  when i am trying to change name from inputbox,, <input> tag in DIV was not showing,, simply name was going change, remaining all elements are not showing, means input tag or anything else in that label div..

Answer (score 1):

Making DOM related operations on Controller is not good practice. Create a directive and then do the operations. 
Edit: Try below code

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.class = 'col-sm-12';
  $scope.textVal = 'click a button';
  $scope.selectedEvent = {};
  $scope.selectedButton = '';
  $scope.setText = function(element) {
    $scope.selectedEvent = element;
     $scope.textVal = element.currentTarget.innerHTML;
     $scope.selectedButton = element.toElement.id;
  };
  $scope.changeButtonText = function(){
    $scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
    
  }; 
});

app.directive('addClassName', function() {
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        link: function (scope,elm, attr) {
          elm.click(function( e, rowid ) {
             var btn = angular.element('#'+attr.btnselected);
             var inpt = angular.element('textVal');
             console.log(btn);
             //if (inpt.val() != '') {
                if (attr.txt == 'Large') {
                  btn.attr('class','');
                  btn.addClass('btn btn-primary col-sm-12');
                } else if (attr.txt == 'Medium') {
                  btn.attr('class','');
                  btn.addClass('btn btn-primary col-sm-6');
                } else {
                  btn.attr('class','');
                  btn.addClass('btn btn-primary col-sm-4');
                } 
             //}
             
          });
        }
     } 
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.col-sm-12 {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7 !important;
    border-color: #2e6da4 !important;
}

.col-sm-6 {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #f89406 !important;
   border-color: #f89406 !important;

}
.col-sm-4 {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #000 !important;
   border-color: #000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myapp'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div>
  <button type="button" id= 'one' class="btn btn-primary {{class}}" ng-click="setText($event)">one</button>
  <button type="button" id= 'two' class="btn btn-primary {{class}}" ng-click="setText($event)">two</button>
  <button type="button" id= 'three' class="btn btn-primary {{class}}" ng-click="setText($event)">three</button>
</div><br>
<div>
<input type="text" id = 'textVal' ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeButtonText()">//change button name here//<br>

<input type="radio" name="button" txt="Large" btnSelected= '{{selectedButton}}' add-class-name>Large
<input  type="radio" name="button" txt="Medium" add-class-name btnSelected= '{{selectedButton}}'>medium
<input  type="radio" name="button" txt="Small" add-class-name btnSelected= '{{selectedButton}}'>Small 
</div>//change button class here//
</body>

</html>
```

Check this plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/spYR8kcndwZ2yfqXQ9iW?p=preview

Comment: in ur code.. changing all buttons class.. i want to change only selected button class.. means[1stButton to large, 2ndButton to Medium, 3rdButton to small]

Comment: can u pls check ur code once again,, not changing class names.. :(

Answer (score 1):

ngClass needs an expression or {'className': expression } object.

## EDIT

Since you want to update them seperatly i made a new [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q02N2YiZknKfke97kZDj?p=preview)

### old code

You could do something like this

JS:

```
$scope.getClass = function(){
  return $scope.class;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" ng-class="getClass()" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setText($event)">two</button>
```

Comment: It tried modifying your plunker and it works for me. All button change sizes

Comment: can u pls send ur modified plunker to me?

Comment: my requirement is how to change 3buttons in to 3 different class names,, but in your code those 3buttons going in to same class

Comment: Oh, in that case, give me a few minutes and i will update my answer

Comment: there is no result ur new code,, can u pls check it and send me again?

Comment: @VijjuSena forgot to make it public, should show now

Answer (score 1):

First point: remember that `class` is a reserved word in javascript (i.e. don't use it for variables). People often use `klass` as a variable name instead.

Regarding your problem, there are lot's of ways to do this. My favourite would be a button directive with an isolate scope, but I'll try to keep this answer simple.

I think the following code does what you want.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setText($event)">one</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setText($event)">two</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setText($event)">three</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeButtonText()">//change button name here//
    <br>

    <input ng-click="changetoLarge()" type="radio" name="button">Large
    <input ng-click="changetoMedium()" type="radio" name="button">medium
    <input ng-click="changetoSmall()" type="radio" name="button">Small
  </div>//change button class here//
</body>
```

...

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.textVal = 'click a button';
  $scope.selectedButton = null;

  $scope.setText = function(event) {
    $scope.selectedButton = event.target;
    $scope.textVal = $scope.selectedButton.innerHTML;
  };
  $scope.changeButtonText = function(){
    $scope.selectedButton.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
  };
  $scope.changetoLarge = function(){
    $scope.selectedButton.className = 'btn btn-primary col-sm-12'
  }
  $scope.changetoMedium = function(){
    $scope.selectedButton.className = 'btn btn-primary col-sm-6'
  }
  $scope.changetoSmall = function(){
    $scope.selectedButton.className = 'btn btn-primary col-sm-4'
  }
});
```

I didn't like the way you were referecing your dom elements, so I changed that. Other than that the main change is to set the class on the selectedButton directly, without using Angular interpolation in your html. Simple and gives you the result you want.

Comment: sry showing some issues in ur code,, can u pls check it and tell to me?  this is ur [plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/J5hQ4Fd8drYbIYBkbtfd?p=preview)..

Comment: if i put **selectedButton = {}** instead of using **null** .. working correctly,, but how can we catch selected button active class into radio input,, means if i selected 2nd button was in medium, radio button have to go to checked medium radio..

Comment: Setting `selectedButton` to `null` means you have to select a button before you begin; setting it to `{}` is fine too.

Comment: Ah, you want a two way binding. I didn't catch that. I'd go with one of the other answers then.

Comment: hi can u pls tell me how to replace class without remove class then add class form ur code

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to below..

```
$scope.changetoLarge = function(){
       angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).removeClass($scope.selectedE vent.currentTarget.className)

      angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).addClass('btn btn-primary col-sm-12')
 }
  $scope.changetoMedium = function(){
       angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).removeClass($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget.className)
       angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).addClass('btn btn-primary col-sm-6')
   }
   $scope.changetoSmall = function(){
     angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).removeClass($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget.className)
     angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).addClass('btn btn-primary col-sm-3')
 }
```

Comment: thank you :) u done a great job .. how to make active radio button on selected button? means if i changed class name of 1st button me medium and changed 2nd button to small, if i go to 1st button again have to show selected radio button to medium,, means have to happen 2way binding,, can u tell this to me pls

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ID's to uniquely identify the buttons

Comment: You *could* use IDs, but you don't *need* to.

Comment: @NeilAtkinson - shall we settle on "should"?

Answer (score 0):

I did change a lot of refactoring in code, as I don't like the way you are playing with DOM `element.currentTarget.innerHTML`. Refactoring will make less repeatative code by converting it to array and rendering the same using `ng-repeat`.

Also by having `buttons` array, that will contains each button information. Each element of array will represent a button & you can have any special information to button element.

**Markup**

```
<div>
  <button ng-class="button.class" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$parent.selected = $index" 
      ng-repeat="button in buttons">
        {{button.text}}
  </button>

  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="buttons[selected || 0].text" value="click a button">
    <br>

    <input ng-click="changetoLarge()" type="radio" name="button">Large
    <input ng-click="changetoMedium()" type="radio" name="button">medium
    <input ng-click="changetoSmall()" type="radio" name="button">Small
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.changetoLarge = function() {
    $scope.buttons[$scope.selected].class = 'col-sm-12'
}
$scope.changetoMedium = function() {
    $scope.buttons[$scope.selected].class = 'col-sm-6'
}
$scope.changetoSmall = function() {
    $scope.buttons[$scope.selected].class = 'col-sm-4'
}
$scope.buttons = [{
    text: 'Feed',
    id: '1',
    class: "col-sm-12"
  }, {
    text: 'the',
    id: '2',
    class: "col-sm-12"
  }, {
    text: 'Input',
    id: '3',
    class: "col-sm-12"
}];
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/XDAP1YcS0E4jpOmAX4DC?p=preview)

Comment: @PankajParker thats ok,, but don't have to use anywhere ng-repeat in my code.. because another functionalities won't work to me..

Comment: @VijjuSena my whole point behind this answer is `$scope.buttons` is the base array for button..that will have the special information in it.. as you can have its own information on element level'